# Packing and unpacking a high-precision floating point number with Python

Tags: python, floating-point, pack, unpack

Using Python's struct modul I'd like to successfully unpack a high-precision

floating point number: 9.80908925027372e-44. The value is being read

from a binary file.

```
import sys
import struct

filename = 'example.bin'

packer = struct.Struct('icd')

values = (42, b'\x00', 9.80908925027372e-44)

package = packer.pack(*values)

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    
    f.write(package)

f.close()

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:

        first_line = f.readline(struct.calcsize('icd'))

        print(packer.unpack(first_line)) 

f.close()
```

However, the obtained collection of values

is the following: (42, 0.0, False).

Can anyone please point out what's the cause

of the floating-point number not being appropriately

decoded?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with your code, copy & pasting & running returns `(42, b'\x00', 9.80908925027372e-44)` .  Also you don't need the `f.close()` lines as you're using a context manager so the file is closed at the end of the `with` block automatically

Comment: You don't use `readline()` on binary files, because the data isn't organised as lines. Just use `read()`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Then how to substitute for readline()?

Comment: Use plain `read()` instead, to get the whole file, or with a specific number of bytes if you want less than the entire file.